# In windows,code is able to fetch information about internal battery but not for external battery

Tags: c, windows

In windows, my code is able to fetch information about internal battery but same code is not able to fetch information about external battery... values are displaying as NA/Invalid/0 for External battery. Kindly help me in this. 
I am using the windows API below:

```
DeviceIoControl(hBattery[num],
    IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION,
    &bqi[num],
    sizeof(bqi[num]),
    &name,
    sizeof(name),
    &dwOut[num],
    NULL);
```

Kindly help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`GetSystemPowerStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-getsystempowerstatus) function?

Comment: At the end of the description of the `IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION` control code in the VC documentation is a link to _Enumerating Battery Devices_ example. Try that example to see if you get the info of the external battery.

Comment: Thanks Paul and Weather for your quick response.

Comment: Hi Paul-I am new to this API and also I don't have any idea on this much.
I think you are asking to check the one which is mentioned below;

#define IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION \
        CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_BATTERY, 0x11, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS)
If not so,kindly let me know in details what should I look into exactly please.

Comment: Weather Vane --->I am facing problem in this function only while I am using this code for external battery..Not able to fetch any of the battery component's information.

Comment: @LushiGrey If you want to respond to a comment, you should add a @ before the name. Then the author will get a notification about your coment.

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that no one knows how you call the functions and inspect the results.

Comment: @ Gerhardh Thanks for your information.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie-I am new to this API and also I don't have any idea on this much. I think you are asking to check the one which is mentioned below; #define IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION \ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_BATTERY, 0x11, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS) If not so,kindly let me know in details what should I look into exactly please.

Comment: I mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/power/enumerating-battery-devices

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie -->how can I paste my code here because it's displaying too long characters.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie--> I am feeling like there is problem in the below mentioned line(my code is also similiar to link which you have provided);
// Enumerated a battery.  Ask it for information.
              HANDLE hBattery = 
                      CreateFile(pdidd->DevicePath,
                                 GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                 FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                 NULL,
                                 OPEN_EXISTING,
                                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                 NULL);